How do I create a disk partition in Ubuntu 22.04 for installing Fyde OS?
Recently, I tried using the FydeOS for my system but I did not have a pendrive to boot from there. So, on some quick googling, I found that I would need to create a partition in my drive and then boot from there. For that, I tried using the GParter and the Disks application but to no avail.

The above image is the disk info of my device. The below image shows the error which I receive on trying to create a partition.

Eve if I try to resize, the max size and the min size for that partition is the same.(refer the image below)

My device previously had windows 10 OS but it was too slow for my GB ram device so I decided to use Ubuntu but now I wish to switch to FydeOS. So, how do I create a partition for it?

This question is similar to: How to resize partitions?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@mook765, I do not find a solution there without the use of live USB which I do not have(I have a 3.7gb onee and that is not enough). I have edited the question and add another screenshot to show the issue with resizing

Gparted Live will be small enough for your pendrive, the download is only 550 MB.

Yeah I found a 64bit one and not a 32bit one. I will try to do it with the 64bit but I don't think it work'

If you need a 32 bit version, use the i686`-iso.

@mook765 if I am not wrong, I am supposed to boot the system with gparted live? Like I should flash it using a software like etcher and then boot using the pendrive? Im not sure how to do this as I am really bad at this

Please take a deep look at the link I provided. It include further links such as installation instructions
